# How to actually set final_response on dialogflow and google actions

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have this code below in which I am trying to create a MediaObject to load an audio file, I am using the exact code from google [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses).

The error I get is final_response must be set. Even if I use conv.close as suggested by one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929656/dialogflow-v2-api-actions-v2-api-malformedresponse-final-response-must-be-s)

What is the actual way to set final_response?

```
function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
     agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
 let conv = agent.conv();
 conv.ask(new Suggestions('Suggestion Chips'));
 conv.close(new MediaObject({
  name: 'Jazz in Paris',
  url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3',
  description: 'A funky Jazz tune',
  icon: new Image({
    url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/album_art.jpg',
    alt: 'Media icon',
  }),
}));
conv.ask(new Suggestions(['suggestion 1', 'suggestion 2']));

  }
```

Comment: You are mixing conv.ask and conv.close in the same response. Is there a reason you're doing that?

Comment: only one reason, nothing was working so I tried everything. :)

Comment: I suspect that the problem isn't with the code you've included above, but with how your app is structured. Check [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-webhook-template-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js) for an example (rather than just a snippet like you saw in the docs), and if you could include more of your code (specifically where you call app.intent) that would be helpful.

Comment: @lukedavis  [this](https://gist.github.com/sherazlodhi/112e97cb881bfd38071fc386042c6ff1) is the complete code. and [this](https://gist.github.com/sherazlodhi/53dd79ac0212528209819901eb9360c4). both from google provided samples

Answer (score 0):

When mixing the AoG client library and the Dialogflow fulfillment library the latter needs to have the conversation added explicitly with **agent.add(conv)** somewhere. Consider maybe adding **agent.add(conv)** on line 55 of your code [here](https://gist.github.com/sherazlodhi/112e97cb881bfd38071fc386042c6ff1#file-webhook-firebas-L55) like the code [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/samples/actions-on-google/functions/index.js#L62) shows.

Also, conv.close ends the interaction, so just keep an eye on that as on line [54](https://gist.github.com/sherazlodhi/112e97cb881bfd38071fc386042c6ff1#file-webhook-firebas-L54) you call conv.close and then conv.ask after it (which just won't be called and maybe will cause problems).

Comment: thanks for the answer, Please check the latest code [here](https://gist.github.com/sherazlodhi/c5d350c15912226fc158299d9c48a9fa) , I still get the same error. and my package file [here](https://gist.github.com/sherazlodhi/fca21b5da2f870e11343fffd02e8bb35)