# Action using web-fulfillment with firebase throwing MalformedResponse 'final_response' must be set

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Env : Using firebase cloud deployed google action.
Action is using webhook to get results from functions.
I am using Blaze plan so calling external URL should be legit.
I am using dialogflow V2.

Part of my function's job is doing the following:
I make an external API request using the following (Masked code detail):

```
var requestObj = require('request');
var options = {
  url: 'my url',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    result = JSON.parse(body).element;
    console.log('Title 0  ' + result);
  }
}

requestObj(options, callback);
```

Once I have the result, I parse it and use it.

Following are my reference points that I tried from stack overflow solutions:

- [Dialogflow v2 API + Actions v2 API: MalformedResponse 'final_response' must be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929656/dialogflow-v2-api-actions-v2-api-malformedresponse-final-response-must-be-s)

Would appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: I think you should put your question in the body of your text too. Otherwise as you are using firebase you have access to the logs with 'firebase functions:log', can you tell us what does this give to you?

Comment: And do you have a conv.ask somewhere in your code or do you only use console logs? It could be due to that, otherwise can you show us when you are calling conv.Ask ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases involving the MalformedResponse and an asynchronous call using something like `request`, the problem is that you're sending the response outside of the callback. Frequently this is because the library is expecting a Promise and you are handling things in a non-promise like way.

My usual practice is:

- use the [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) library (or the [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) library)
- in one of the `then` sections where you get the results, make sure you call `conv.ask()`
- make sure you return the promise itself.

So (very roughly)

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');

var options = {
  uri: 'https://example.com/api',
  json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
};

return request(options)
  .then( response => {
    // The response will be a JSON object already. Do whatever with it.
    var value = response.whatever.you.want;
    return conv.ask( `The value is ${value}. What now?` );
  });
```

Comment: Made the suggested changes, with one extra line
 let conv = agent.conv(); 
still complaining: MalformedResponse
'final_response' must be set. Please suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50422410/6114925 will be help as my issue is same as this user.

Comment: I've changed the answer so it uses request-promise-native. Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Yes it actually fixed the issue, I realized you made the comment about the node version being 6 is causing this and you replicated it. So I just took that answer to solve my issue.

Comment: Great! Glad we were able to get you working. If an answer has helped, upvoting and/or accepting the answer is always appreciated.